# Sending captured image from flash to Asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, flash

I am using `Asp.net/C#` in my application , I am using a `.swf file` which is placed on my `Default.aspx` page to capture images from webcam, I have a requirement that the captured image should be sent to `server` or `aspx page` without storing it on the clients machine , Anybody could help me out please . 
Any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this can help you:

```
    string strPhoto = Request.Form["imageData"]; //Get the image from flash file
    byte[] photo = Convert.FromBase64String(strPhoto);
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("PathInTheServer", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
    BinaryWriter br = new BinaryWriter(fs);
    br.Write(photo);
    br.Flush();
    br.Close();
    fs.Close();
```

Comment: where do I use this , could you elaborate a bit more.Thanks for your reply

Comment: you can see more details in the following link:  http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/38150-Capture-save-images-from-Web-camera.aspx

Comment: thanks but it is saving it in c drive , I need to store it on the server ...thanks

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that if you wrote in asp path for file it goes to the path in the server. it can't go to the path in the local machine. the local machine for him is the server

Comment: I think you are right , so do you think I can store the image  , let's say in the Images folder on the server with that.Thanks

Comment: of course, why not? the images folder it's part of the project folder? if so, you can write something like that: Server.MapPath("images/")+"imageName.jpg". that's if the images folder is under the root folder of the project. hope you understand me...

Comment: ya it is under the root folder , will try this , thanks for your interest.

Comment: I like this. It's my pleasure! but if it realy helped you please vote to my answer and mark it as the answer. thanks!